# On-line Ball tree Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I need a method to construct a ball tree in an on-line manner for Nearest Neighbour search. Before this I have been using Scikit-learn's implementation of the Ball Tree Nearest Neighbour module to carry out my scientific calculations but it is not feasible when I have new data arriving and the entire Ball Tree has to be reconstructed every time.  I have not found much literature on implementing an on-line algorithm, the wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree) suggests an off-line method, so I wanted to pose the question to the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a space-filling-curve. Translate the co-ordinate to a binary and interleave it. Maybe treat it as a base-4 number.